# How far can you move the toilet away from the vent stack in NJ?

Tags: toilet, code-compliance, drain-waste-vent

I plan on moving the toilet bowl to a different spot in the bathroom, further away from the stack. What is the maximum horizontal distance? Is it 9 feet?

As per New Jersey Plumbing Code 2018, [12.8.4](https://up.codes/viewer/new_jersey/nj-plumbing-code-2018/chapter/12/vents-and-venting#12.8.4):

> **12.8.4 Siphonic Fixtures**
>
> For water closets, clinical sinks, and flushing-rim service sinks with
> integral traps, the distance between the outlet of the fixture and its
> vent connection shall not exceed three (3) feet vertically and nine
> (9) feet horizontally.

Could someone confirm that this is the relevant part of the code?

[image]

Comment: Water closets are usually a more English term for toilets.  Would worry about the slope needed, 9 feet will need a minimum of 2 and 1/4 inch slope.

Comment: Yes 9’ is what it states so you really answer your question, that distance can be at an angle just the distance from the closet flange to the vent stack is 9’

Comment: @crip659 slope may be be 1/8" per foot minimum for 3" and larger pipe depending on the local code.

Comment: @ickybus  You really want to go with minimum slope for a toilet if you don't need to?

Comment: @crip659 sure, why not?  toilets can get stuck in no-mans-land of slope when you're between 1/4"/foot and 45 degrees where liquids outpace solids.  If your flush water runs too quickly, it won't carry your poop with it.  but 1/8" isn't an issue.  1/16" probably wouldn't be either, though i'ven't personally tried it.  Codes are conservative for a reason.